# TestNG version number differs in pom.xml and in execution log

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, testng

I added `TestNG` dependency in `pom.xml` file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I see following during execution of test:

> ... ... TestNG 6.8.9beta by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com) ...

I just wondering, why isn't version 6.14.3 in use?

This is also logged as a TestNG bug [GITHUB-1802](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1802)

Comment: Tried reproducing the problem with `IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.4 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-181.5087.20, built on May 17, 2018` and TestNG plugin version `TestNG-J version : 8.0`. Unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: My environment: `IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-181.4445.78, built on April 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b27 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 8.1 6.3`

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches" and "Refresh" from Maven tool window?

Comment: @y.bedrov : Yes, but I didn't use older version of TestNG in this project.